# BlueJ issue with importing packages

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

I am currently an AP Computer Science teacher and in my classroom we have desktops running Virtually.  2 out of my 20 computers being used are having issues with BlueJ not recognizing the sort method from the Arrays class. They correctly imported java.util.* but when we compile it says method not recognized.  What would cause it only to be happening to 2 students and no one else?

Thanks for any help!

```
import java.util.*;
public static int range(int[] a) 
{
    int[] copy = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        copy[i] = a[i];
    }
    Arrays.sort(copy);
    return copy[copy.length - 1] - copy[0];
}
```

Comment: Please post your code and the exact error message. And check that your computer really has an installed _JDK_ (not _JRE_) and that BlueJ was configured correctly to use it.

Comment: import java.util.*;
public static int range(int[] a) 
{
    int[] copy = new int[a.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
    {
        copy[i] = a[i];
    }
    Arrays.sort(copy);
    return copy[copy.length - 1] - copy[0];
}
The error message that comes up is "cannot find method Arrays.sort(int[]).

Comment: Since we are running virtual desktops it should be the same JDK for all computers that is where I am getting stumped.  Why it worked for most students and not the other 2.

Comment: Please post the code in the question, not in a comment. Do these students have the exact same code? No typos?

Comment: No typos similar not identical code, this is one of the students code.

Comment: I guess you just omitted the class? Have you tried `import java.util.Arrays;` instead? Does the compiler "allow" other methods of the `Arrays` class? Like `Arrays.sort(new long[]{1, 2, 3})`?

Comment: @Alyse there are so many ways to debug this problem. Have you tried running the codes in the console or use another IDE? If it works when you run the program else where but not in blueJ, I am sure reinstalling it will solve the problem. If you can't reinstall it, then just ensure the settings are similar to other work stations'.

Comment: Yeah, I omitted the class.  It wouldn't allow any method from the Arrays class.  I tried that import statement as well.  Interestingly enough I had a different student this class and tried the code on that computer and it worked.  I guess I have to have those two students profiles re-imaged.  Could that be possible that two students lost their JDK on their profile?

Comment: Since we don't know how your system works, we can't say that for sure. But an administrator of your school could check that.